# Converting certain columns into different data type and filter those columns

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame which looks as following,

[image]

I need to convert those columns which are starting with Distance* into data type integer(Currently they are in string format) and then further filter those.

I could do it like this,separately for each column but my data frame is big and has many those columns

```
a.Distance0=a.Distance0.astype(int)
a.Distance1=a.Distance1.astype(int)
```

Also after that I need to filter out those rows based on columns which are starting with Distance and get two columns as out put, so what I am aming as a final output from my input data frame is,

```
 Head1     Header   Dis
    ABC    SAP     115590
    ABC    GRN     426250
    KLM    DSQ    120001
```

I have tried to get there with the following piece of code, That is I am filtering those rows which are starting with Distance >=100000 and I am wanted only those rows with three column values as I mentioned above.
   This is what I tried but this solution gives me out all columns

```
a.loc[a[a[a.columns[pd.Series(a.columns).str.startswith('Distance')]] >= 100000].dropna(how='all', axis=0).index]
```

But it's giving result but I am getting those rows with all columns like this,

```
RNA             PC                  NA  PC0   Strand0 Distance0   PC1 Strand1 Distance1
RP11 RNF223 (+11559), AGRN (+42625) 0   RNF223  +   115590  AGRN    +   42625
RP13 CORT (-19440), APITD1 (+177)   0   CORT    -   254880  APITD1  +   177
```

Any help or suggestions would be really great.!!!

Comment: Could you order the dataframes you wrote so that they actually have columns? It's hard to read this way.

Comment: Head1 is a duplicate column, edit the dataframe when you get a chance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I've renamed your first Head1 column to be Header (you have duplicate columns in your example).

I set up my Dataframe differently than yours, but close enough. I didn't fill out the columns that are irrelevant to the question.

Here's my setup code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([],
                   columns=["Header",
                   "LongHeader",
                   "Head0",
                   "Strand0",
                   "Distance0",
                   "Head1",
                   "Strand1",
                   "Distance1",
                   "Head2",
                   "Strand2",
                   "Distance2"])
df["Header"] = ["ABC", "EFG", "HIJ", "KLM", "SOS"]
df["LongHeader"] = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
df["Head0"] = ["SAP", "HES3", "CORT", "AAD", "MFA"]
df["Strand0"] = ["+", "-", "-", "-", "-"]
df["Distance0"] = ["115590", "6350", "19440", "25488", "11174"]
df["Head1"] = ["GRN", "CMT", "API", "DH", "13A2"]
df["Strand1"] = ["+", "-", "-", "-", "-"]
df["Distance1"] = ["426250", "1902", "177", "1341", "19763"]
df["Head2"] = ["None", "None", "None", "DSQ", "None"]
df["Strand2"] = ["+", "-", "-", "-", "-"]
df["Distance2"] = ["None", "None", "None", "120001", "None"]

print df
```

Which gives data similar to your example:

```
  Header LongHeader Head0 Strand0 Distance0 Head1 Strand1 Distance1 Head2  
0    ABC          1   SAP       +    115590   GRN       +    426250  None   
1    EFG          2  HES3       -      6350   CMT       -      1902  None   
2    HIJ          3  CORT       -     19440   API       -       177  None   
3    KLM          4   AAD       -     25488    DH       -      1341   DSQ   
4    SOS          5   MFA       -     11174  13A2       -     19763  None
```

Here's the code to do the work. The main idea was to extract the Headx and Distancex columns, and simply stack them on top of each other. Then change the dtype of Distance to be an int, and only keep rows that have Distance >= 100000.

```
frames_to_concat = []
for col in df:
    if col.startswith("Dis"):
        dis_num = col[-1] # Extract the # from a column like Distance# or Dis#
        frame_to_concat = df[["Header", "Head" + dis_num, "Distance" + dis_num]]
        frame_to_concat.columns = ["Header", "Head", "Distance"]
        frames_to_concat.append(frame_to_concat)

stacked_columns = pd.concat(frames_to_concat)
stacked_columns = stacked_columns[stacked_columns["Distance"] != "None"]
stacked_columns["Distance"] = stacked_columns["Distance"].astype(int)
result = stacked_columns[stacked_columns["Distance"] > 100000]

print result
```

Which gives:

```
# Output:
  Header Head  Distance
0    ABC  SAP    115590
0    ABC  GRN    426250
3    KLM  DSQ    120001
```

Next time you ask a question, don't make it so hard on potential answerers. Provide setup code!!!

You'll have to modify this solution just a bit to line up with your actual column names, I'm not sure what they should actually be called due to the duplicate column issue. HTH!

Comment: I think this is the correct approach, I used the same one. Nevertheless, when you collect the digit before concatening your columns, it might be wrong if it is above 10.

Comment: Good catch. I'm at work now, but I'll fix whenever I can

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the type of every column starting with `Distance`, you can use a loop:

```
list_col = []
for col in a.columns:
    if (len(col) > 8) & (col[:8] == 'Distance'):
        list_col.appen(col)
a[list_col] = a[list_col].astype(int)
```

Then you create a dataframe concatenating the different Distance values:

```
frames = []
for i in len(list_col):
    temp = df[['Head1','Header'+str(i),list_col[i]]]
    temp.columns = ['Head1','Header','Distance']
    frames.append(temp)
output = pd.concat(drames)
```

(Note that this implies your column names to be well formated, you might have to adapt it to the actual names in the `append`)

Then you filter:

```
output = out[out.Distance >= 100000]
```

This might not work at first try on your dataframe because I assumed your dataframe columns (only the one that interest us) are called like this:

```
Head1      Header0    Distance0     Header1    Distance1    Header2    Distance2
```

And so on... (once again, we don't care about the other columns as they don't interfere in this code)

Comment: The name of the Columns starts with Distance* so the names are Distance0,distance1, Distance2..DistanceN. And many Distance column has Nan values .

Comment: Yes it is far better thank you! But how do you want to create the dataframe with three columns? More precisely, what is `Distance` column? Is it a sum over the all the columns containing `Distance` or the value in `Distance0`?
Can N be over 10?

Comment: But how do you want to create the dataframe with three columns? --I have shown in my question now ..how the data frame with 3 column should like from the input dataframe.More precisely, what is Distance column? Is it a sum over the all the columns containing Distance or the value in Distance0? .--No each Distance column is independent.Each distance correspond to there preceeding column named as Head*

Comment: Ok then what is the column `Distance` in your output? And same for `PC`

Comment: So, for example, the third row of my output see the first value KLM has DSQ with distance >100000 , but in the input, KLM has DSQ , AAD and DH  but only  DSQ is in our filter criteria so out put has only DSQ. Head1     PC   Distance
   KLM    DSQ     120001

Comment: Ok I'm starting to get it. Then for the first row, as both `Dis0` and `Dis1` are over 100000, do you want your output to get two rows with 3 columns or one row with 5 columns?

Comment: I would like to have output with three columns , and I know the first column value would be repeating in some cases but its Ok.I would like to have the output with 3 columns.

Comment: Like in my question if you see the first two rows ABC and ABC its repeating but the second and third column has different values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116802/discussion-between-ysearka-and-user1017373).